# Find crossing lines and count also

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, splitting, count, crossing

I have two line feature classes.

One road line (long line) and second is hookline i.e entry point to house (short line).

Reference screen shot

[image]

In the above screen shot I have three shapefiles

1. Road Ways (RED)
2. Hookline (Blue Entry Lines to House )
3. Houses (Yellow Boxs)

I need to select which hooklines crosses the Road and how many times crossed the road, need that count also. in the above figure count is 6

Comment: Intersect - summary statistics

Answer (score 0):

I created a test dataset as shown below:

[image: data]

Simply use the [Select by Location tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm#) with the the spatial selection method set to *Are crossed by the outline of* to achieve this:

[image: Selected]

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd but it is not working properly it is selecting not crossed lines also

Comment: In my test data the hook line goes from the house to the road line, except in the case of a line crossing a road. You need to edit your question and add more information about the topological relationship that your hook lines have with the roads. You may not be able to answer this question in a programatically way.